# mysql echo does not retrieve word after a space in textbox

Tags: php, mysql

I have a textbox which i echo data from mysql. However if there is a space in the mysql database feild it does not show the word after the space. For example. If there was 'Joe Bloggs' in the database and I echoed it to the text field it would only show 'Joe'. Confused as to why.

PHP:

textbox:

```
 <input name="name" title="Enter Name" size="23" maxlength="250" value=<?php echo $row['name']?>>
```

Comment: -1. One have to verify their statements. echo doesn't "retrieve" anything and never miss anything. Basic HTML also essential for the every PHP user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting your value in quotes:

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" title="Enter Name" size="23" maxlength="400" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row3['name'])?>">
```

Comment: Made your answer a proper one

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the `value` of your input.

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" title="Enter Name" size="23" maxlength="400" value="<?php echo $row3['name']?>">
```

This should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have quotes around your attributes, in this case, `value`

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" title="Enter Name" size="23" maxlength="400" value="<?php echo $row3['name']?>" />
```