# How can I make my html code output the data in a valid way?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to output the contents of my MySQL user table, i have the code set up in a way in which administrators can add, edit and delete rows within the table. After looking into the issue a bit more however I found that the html code is outputting the values in an awkward way, as it's only counting the first word in the column as a valid value so it ignores the other words. How can I go about fixing this?

For example say i'm trying to output an album called Skulls & Bones the output on the table will just be Skulls.

**Admin_Album_Page.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>View Album Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();
require_once 'ConnectorCode.php';

//mysql_query command is used to select data from Albums table
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_Albums");

//Echos setting established onto the main table
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Album ID</th> <th>Album Name</th> <th>Number Of Tracks</th>        
<th> Genre </th> <th>Track ID</th> </tr>";

//Results are looped and then displayed in tables while($row =     mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<form action=Admin_Album_Page.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=albumid value=" . $row['Album_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=albumname value=" . $row['Album_Name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=numberoftracks value=" . $row['Number_Of_Tracks'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=genre value=" . $row['Genre'] . " </td>" ;
echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=artistid value=" . $row['Artist_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['Album_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=Update" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=Delete" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
}

echo "<form action=Admin_Artist_Page.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ualbumname></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=unumberoftracks></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ugenre></td>";
echo "<td><input type=number name=uartistid></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=Add" ." </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";

//Connection is closed
mysqli_close($conn);
?>


<p><a href="Admin.php">Return to main page</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560490/mysql-echo-does-not-retreive-word-after-a-space-in-textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your HTML rendering.

You need to change your code to this:

```
echo "<form action=\"Admin_Album_Page.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"number\" name=\"albumid\" value=\"" . $row['Album_id'] . "\" </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"text\" name=\"albumname\" value=\"" . $row['Album_Name'] . "\" </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"number\" name=\"numberoftracks\" value=\"" . $row['Number_Of_Tracks'] . "\" </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"text\" name=genre value=" . $row['Genre'] . " </td>" ;
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"number\" name=\"artistid\" value=\"" . $row['Artist_id'] . "\" </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $row['Album_id'] . "\" </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"update\" value=\"Update" . "\" </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete" . "\" </td>";
echo "</form>"

echo "<form action=\"Admin_Artist_Page.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ualbumname\"></td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"unumberoftracks\"></td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ugenre\"></td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"uartistid\"></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"add\" value=\"Add" ."\" </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
```

Explaining:

HTML works the following way:

```
<tag attribute="value"></tag>
```

You can't simply call it by

```
<tag attribute=value></tag>
```

In the code that I've showed you, you want to make sure that the `"` symbol is part of the string, so you escape it using `\`

Comment: How can I make my queries work with the fields now though? Such as: `if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_Artist SET Artist_id='$_POST[artistid]', Artist_Name='$_POST[artistname]' WHERE Artist_id='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysqli_query ($conn, $UpdateQuery);
};`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood what you're asking

Comment: I'm trying to take the names declared within the forms and using them in the queries. But whenever I try to the program keeps declaring the names as update\ or artistid\ is that right?

Comment: It shouldn't! For instance, if I declare the code in PHP `echo "<form action=\"Admin_Album_Page.php\" method=\"post\">";` it should display in the HTML source `<form action="Admin_Album_Page.php" method="post">`

Comment: Then why is Notepad++ showing them as post\ or update\? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108301/discussion-between-jack-rogers-and-rafaelcpalmeida).